# Weird optional class properties in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Suddenly from today, the code below started to occur ts2322 error.
This works well in [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEDS5WgbwLAChrQG5hAVwFMB%20ALmgDs8BbAIwICcBuddTYAe3IgBd69hu7egAoc%20YmUq0GASmStM0bgAsAlhAB0YwtAC82XIWYZoAX3SmgA)

I can't find anything wrong with it, but what's the problem?

I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.56.2

```
class Klass {
  value?: number;

  constructor(value?: number) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't mentioned this, but I assume you're using the nightly builds published in npm as `typescript@next`.  If so, you are likely seeing a preview of a new feature for TypeScript 4.4, "strict optional properties", as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#43947](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/43947).  (UPDATE 2021-06-10) This functionality was originally going to be enabled via a new `--strictOptionalProperties` compiler flag, which would have been included in the [`--strict` suite of compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict). However, according to [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44421#issuecomment-858870879), the flag will be renamed and removed from `--strict`, so anyone who wants to see this behavior in TypeScript 4.4 and above will need to manually enable it, via some compiler flag whose name has not yet been decided.

Strict optional properties will prevent you from *assigning* `undefined` to an optional property, while still allowing you to *read* `undefined` from such a property.  This is more in keeping with how people have wanted optional properties to be for a long time, as evidenced by the (now finally closed) issue [microsoft/TypeScript#13195](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195).

Anyway, this means it is no longer safe to assign a value read from an optional parameter into an optional property of the same type, without first checking if it is `undefined`:

```
class Klass {
  value?: number;

  constructor(value?: number) {
    if (value !== undefined) this.value = value;
  }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1&strict=true&ts=4.4.0-dev.20210605#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAhEATA6gSwC4AsBlXAJ23lwHkZdsB7UAGwAUS6YITbokBvAKCRJ4jEFChIA0qPF9BQpADcQjAK4QA-AC4kwVWABGnANz95Q+AyilVFOiQAUytZp17DnAJRyFCgtigAOmd1JABeJRV1YyQAelikTjYSAEJzJABfeSys-lBIWARkADFsAA9i+2IyCmpaBhVWdk5uCQF5ETEJaS6fBRDXXX0jElN0y2BrEltceycowfcR7wFfIWwAMyR5lyQUsIjVYHQIDexgCHRvfyCB8MiXU18soVyMoA)

Comment: I have VsCode 1.56.2 but not typescript@next and I get these errors with typescript v4.1.2

Comment: @AlessioCancian there's no mechanism whereby you would see this particular error (not being able to assign `undefined` to an optional property) if you are truly using TS 4.1; without sitting with you at your computer I can't say for certain what's going on, but if I were you I'd quadruple check your assumptions (e.g., that you are really using the version of TS you think you are; that you are really seeing the same error; that you are really merely trying to assign an `undefined` value to an optional property, etc), and then if you don't catch the issue, try to make a [mcve] in a new question.

Comment: I found the problem, my project uses typescript v4.1.2 but VsCode was using 4.4.0-dev.

I had to change TypeScript version from the bottom status bar to `Use Workspace Version` instead of `Use VS Code's Version`, first time I see this setting 