# HTMLInputElement - types of property "X" are incompatible - type "Y | undefined" is not assignable to type "Y"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I recently changed my project from my Hackintosh into an M1 MacBook and after installing dependencies I got this error where it previously didn't exist.

Basically, it comes up when I want to assign a property that is optional to an HTML element. It says the property cannot be undefined, even doe it is optional in that element.

Here is a print screen from one example, in this case, it's from a controlled Input:

[Printscreen of controlled input error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yi7mz.png)

The markup code for this controlled input:

```
        <input
          ref={inputRef}
          id={id || name}
          value={value}
          data-lpignore='true'
          {...{
            name,
            type,
            inputMode,
            placeholder,
            disabled,
            required,
            size,
            list,
            minLength,
            maxLength,
            pattern,
            readOnly,
            onChange,
            onInvalid
          }}
        />
```

Most of these properties are being defined using PropTypes as optional parameters (strings, booleans, numbers, or funcs accordingly).

For example, the type of list is "string | undefined" but this generates the error mentioned above and shown in the print screen.

I've looked through the code for @types and tried reconfiguring my tsconfig.json but got nothing.

This is tsconfig.json currently:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./node_modules/@dscoimbra/keys-types",
      "./node_modules/@dscoimbra/erp-types",
      "./node_modules/@dscoimbra/credito-habitacao-types",
      "./node_modules/@dscoimbra/seguro-vida-types",
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@images/*": ["images/*"],
      "@scripts/*": ["scripts/*"],
      "@libs/*": ["libs/*"],
      "@styles/*": ["styles/*"],
      "@components/*": ["components/*"],
      "@redux/*": ["redux/*"],
      "@pages/*": ["pages/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using?  It's possible you're running into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67822178/weird-optional-class-properties-in-typescript) but without a [mcve] from you I couldn't be sure.